# How to prevent Prettier from breaking test code from 1 line to multiple lines

Tags: javascript, lint, prettier

Code in question

```
it('will display No Policy Found after fist submit attempt.', () => {
    const policyDetails = {
        partyID: null,
        agreementID: null,
        isValidPolicy: false,
    };
    wrapper.setProps({policyDetails});
    wrapper.setState({submitCount: 1});
    const result = wrapper.instance().displayUserNotices();
    const render = shallow(result)
        .find('UserNotice')
        .find('p');

    expect(render.text()).toEqual(NO_POLICY_USER_NOTICE);
});
```

**I keep writing**

```
const render = shallow(result)
  .find('UserNotice')
  .find('p');
```

**as the desired following 1-liner:**

`const render = shallow(result).find('UserNotice').find('p');`

**But prettier keeps reverting it.**

I tried adding

`noUnexpectedMultiline: true` in the .prettierrc.yml but that didn't work.

Ideas?

Comment: if you don't use multi-line template strings, a simple RegExp can clean that up for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent Prettier from formatting your code, use this comment before the variable/function/etc.

```
// prettier-ignore
```

If you want prettier to ignore multiple lines in Markdown, you can do so as well.

````
<!-- prettier-ignore-start -->
# Headline

```js
const foo      =         'hey';
console.log      (foo);
```
<!-- prettier-ignore-end -->
````

For more information: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: `// prettier-ignore-start` and `// prettier-ignore-end` currently only work in markdown.

Answer (score 1):

Would love to see them add the ability to ignore specific functions, in Javascript, like 'console.log'.   Had to change my snippets to add the //prettier-ignore at the end of every line.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that will happen regularly in your codebase, and you don't want to have `ignore` statements all over your code, and you want to enable going past 80 characters (which Prettier recommends **not** doing), you could increase the width by adding

```
"printWidth": <whatever you want your max column length to be>
```

to your `prettierrc.json`

[Print Width in the docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width)

Alternatively, if you don't want the comments in the code, you can create a [.prettierignore file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#ignoring-files) and add your file to that.

Comment: Even this isn't working. This line got broken up, although it's 76 chars including indentation. My printWidth is 100. 

`expect(await updatedTicket?.ticketNotes).to.be.an('array').of.length(3);`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this @myfashionhub?  Is there a chance it isn't prettier doing this (e.g. autoformat on save in your IDE?)